# DIV within DIV will not display in browser

Tags: html, css

I'm using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 currently, and Firefox 56.

This is my test page code for a HTML page that emulates a printed magazine page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Magazine</title>
    <style>
      .magazine {
        width: 203mm;
        height: 275mm;
        border: 3px solid;
      }
      .advert1 {
        background: yellow;
        width: 179mm;
        height: 249mm;
        padding: 3px solid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="magazine">
    <H1>Content</h1>
    <div class="advert1">
      <H1>CITY AUTOS</h1>
      <p>1993 MERCEDES-BENZ S500, 4 door saloon, slate grey £POA
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div within the div - the .advert1 class does not show up in any browser on Mac, and only .magazine CSS class displays.

There is nothing that hides it within my CSS, so that part can be discounted.

How can I fix this and get the div within the div to display properly using CSS?

Comment: 2 differents css must be used: 1 for screen use: `<style media = "screen">`
1 other for use for paper `<style media = "print">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `advert1` is triggering content blockers from showing the div. In my case, if I disable AdBlock Plus, it shows. Alternatively, renaming the div, as in the example below, also works:

```css
.magazine {
  width: 203mm;
  height: 275mm;
  border: 3px solid;
}

.foo {
  background: yellow;
  width: 179mm;
  height: 249mm;
  padding: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="magazine">
  <H1>Content</h1>
  <div class="foo">
    <H1>CITY AUTOS</h1>
    <p>1993 MERCEDES-BENZ S500, 4 door saloon, slate grey £POA
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```